USING GRID TIED INVERTERS WITH LIMITER IN THE UK
I HAVE A SOLOSOURCE GRID TIED INVERTER WITH LIMITER AND WANT TO USE IT POWERED BY BATTERIES THAT ARE SOLAR CHARGED TO SUPPORT MY HOUSE USEAGE.  IT WILL BE CONNECTED TO MY EXISTING SOLAR INVERTER INSTALLATION.  HAS ANYONE DONE THIS IN THE UK AND DO YOU NEED ENA REGISTRATION FOR THIS TYPE OF INVER WHICH DOES NOT EXPORT TO THE GRID ?

Please fix your post's capitalization – CAPS LOCK reads like shouting, and I'm pretty certain that's not your intent. Welcome here! (Also, great humor having an account called "John Lindley" and then signing a question with "Walter" :-) )
